# Ошибка IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range в Unity

Tags: unity3d

```
    void Update()
{
    //change
    if (enemys != null)
    {

        for(int i= 0; i < enemys.Length; i++)
        {
            //why it's dont works???
            distance[i] = Vector3.Distance(enemys[i].transform.position, transform.position);//wrong
            if (distance[i] < 10f)
            {
                lr.enabled = true;
                positions[i] = enemys[i].transform.position;
                positions[i].z = 0;
                lr.positionCount = positions.Length;
                lr.SetPositions(positions);
            }
        }

    }
```

не хочет находить дистанцию к врагам, хотя врагов успешно находит, а вот дистанцию к ним- нет

Comment: `why it's dont works` - wrong... `why does it not work?` - right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Длина массива `distance` меньше текущего значения `i+1`. Он Вам вообще нужен?

```
double dist = Vector3.Distance(enemys[i].transform.position, transform.position);//right
if (dist < 10f)
{
  ...
```

или

```
distance = new double[enemys.Length];
for(int i= 0; i < enemys.Length; i++)
{
  distance[i] = Vector3.Distance(enemys[i].transform.position, transform.position);
  ...
```